# How far back must one go to know they are Jewish?

Tags: halacha

There are certainly people who are unsure about their Jewish lineage. However, even if they know their mother is jewish, and therefore they are as well, how far back must one go? If they prove their maternal grandmother is Jewish, but cannot go back any further, what would the halacha be? What if they were to be unsure about someone down the line on their maternal side, but had no way to check it out?